# Insert Statement providing the following error in google cloud spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

When tried to insert this data i am getting the following error. Not sure what i am missing but looks silly...

Table Structure

CREATE TABLE PackageItems (
ItemID INT64 NOT NULL,
LocationID INT64 NOT NULL,
PackageID STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
Price FLOAT64 NOT NULL,
OrganizationID INT64,
CreatedBy STRING(MAX),
CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp=true),
LastModifiedBy STRING(MAX),
LastModifiedDateTime TIMESTAMP OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp=true),
) PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationID, LocationID, PackageID, ItemID);

Insert Command
INSERT INTO PackageItems (ItemID, LocationID, PackageID, Price, OrganizationID)
(5,1,"1",12.50,1635931867921)

Error
Syntax error: Unexpected integer literal "5" at line 6, column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the `VALUES` keyword in your insert string:

So instead of:

```sql
INSERT INTO PackageItems (ItemID, LocationID, PackageID, Price, OrganizationID) 
(5,1,"1",12.50,1635931867921)
```

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO PackageItems (ItemID, LocationID, PackageID, Price, OrganizationID) 
VALUES (5,1,'1',12.50,1635931867921)
```

(Also note the change from `"1"` to `'1'` for the string literal.)

Comment: Thank you so much!